# Box-shadow is appearing in all columns in IE

Tags: html, css

I'm giving `box-shadow` to `tr` in a `table` It's working fine in all browsers, but in `IE-10` it's showing `box-shadow` in all `td`, Why?

```css
tr {
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0px #888 inset;
}
```

```html
<table border=0 cellsapcing=0 cellpadding=6>
  <tr>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

> **Chrome**
>
> [image]
>
> **IE 10**
>
> [image]

**Note:** I can't use `border` that's why I gave `box-shadow`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd take a bit of a different approach, and assign the box shadow to the first `th` and `td` elements. This solution moves around the problem, rather than solving it - but is just as valid I feel.

```css
tr th:first-child, tr td:first-child {
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0px #888 inset;
}
```

```html
<table border=0 cellsapcing=0 cellpadding=6>
  <tr>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
    <th>Column</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
    <td>Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually in my project this approach need more customization so I'm considering this options as last option.

Comment: Assigning styles to the physical `<tr>` element is always risky as the way browsers handle them is inconsistent at best. I'd really recommend avoiding styles on table rows as much as possible just to make your life easier.

Comment: Alright! I'm going with your option, but I still want to know why this is happening, thanks for making my life easier :p :D.